# An object, working asynchronously, disappears because there is no reference to it. Is this expected?

Tags: objective-c, properties, automatic-ref-counting

I am new to Objective-C and I just wanted to confirm whether what I'm observing is correct.

This is what's going on:

1. Class `A` creates a `CLLocationManager` object
2. `A` is set as the delegate for the `CLLocationManager` object
3. Location services are activated (in order to have the `CLLocationManager` object call `A` with location updates)

However, location updates are **not** received unless a reference to the `CLLocationManager` object is kept somewhere.

I assume that this is because of ARC. But I am asking because my expectation was that `CLLocationManager` would **not** be deallocated: it has work to do, and the delegate methods receive a reference to the `CLLocationManager`, so why keep an extra property!

Is this interpretation correct?

Is there anything else one can do to keep the `CLLocationManager` object working other than have a property pointing to it?

As an experiment I tried running the steps above within a dispatch queue, but the location updates were **not** received.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your big question is whether this behavior is common and expected.
The answer is the following - it depends. It is an implementation decision. I've seen frameworks working both ways. Usually, you can guess the behavior from the method naming.

For example, a new instance of `CLLocationManager` has to be created before use. Once you have to call `alloc` and `init`, you should always keep the reference.

On the other hand, in frameworks where you don't create a new object, you don't need to hold the reference - for example `[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]` or `[UIApplication sharedApplication]`. The framework holds the reference for you.

Frameworks which use class methods (e.g. `STTwitter`) also typically hold the references for you.

Your following assumption

> and the delegate methods receive a reference to the CLLocationManager

is wrong. The delegate is only a set of methods. It doesn't hold anything if you don't implement it explicitly. Note that you have to also keep a reference to the delegate. The manager won't keep it alive.

Comment: Sulthan, doesn't the implementer of the CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol receive a CLLocationManager object as the first parameter in each of the methods? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html

Comment: @IvanMaeder It does but having a method parameter doesn't magically hold all the objects that can be passed to that method. If you don't have a strong reference to the manager, there will be no object calling the delegate methods (it's the manager who is calling them).

Answer (score 1):

If you are not keeping a reference to the CLLocationManager object it will be deallocated once you reach the end of the scope